# pypyodbc retrieves data very slowly vs PLSQL

Tags: python, oracle, execute, cx-oracle, pypyodbc

I tested the same Oracle query in PLSQL vs Python/pypyodbc.  I'm pulling ~30k rows, which takes 27 seconds in PLSQL, while it takes approximately eight minutes in Python.  My python/pypyodbc code is here:

```
import pandas as pd
import pypyodbc

q0 = '''
    select *
    from weatherview x
    where x.WeatherNodeRCIKey IN (481, 562, 563, 561, 564, 565, 560, 658)
    and x.WeatherDate >= '01-jan-2016'
   '''
try:
con = pypyodbc.connect(driver='{Oracle in OraClient11g_home1}', 
    server='oracle', uid='acct', pwd='Pass', dbq='table')

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(q0)
    q0_rows = cur.fetchall()
    q0_hdnm = [i[0] for i in cur.description]

except Exception as e:
    print("Error: " + str(e))

df0 = pd.DataFrame(q0_rows, columns=q0_hdnm)
df0.head()
```

Its hard for me to believe Python can be so much slower.  I'm curious if this is a server side/client side issue, or perhaps a memory issue.  I don't believe this is related to the dataframe/pandas portion of the code as I have run the code without the last few lines, with the same result.

I'm 90% sure the problem is related to fetchall() being slow.

I would be happy if anyone can point out:

- How to troubleshoot the speed issues (time the DB connection etc)
- Use a different package to pull the query that will be faster
- Alter this code with pypyodbc to work more efficiently

  **EDIT**:  I changed the tags a little, removing [server-side], and adding [cx_Oracle] due to the answer I found below

Comment: A few things. 1. What does the equivalent PL/SQL code look like?  2. Does fetchall() use the array interface? 3. You could use sqltrace to see what differences are at the database level (if any).

Comment: Thanks BobC, 1) the pl/sql code is exactly as above in the triple quotes (my sql may be horrible but as I say it runs much, much faster than the python) 2) unfortunately I don't know the answer to this 3) is sqlTrace run at the DB level or the python level?  Do you have any suggestions as to where I could start with sqlTrace (its new to me)

Answer (score 1):

I found one answer via my "use a different package" option above, using cx_Oracle.  The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle

q0 = '''
    select *
    from weatherview_historical x
    where x.WeatherNodeRCIKey IN (481, 562, 563, 561, 564, 565, 560, 658)
    and x.WeatherDate >= '01-jan-2016'
    and x.WeatherTypeLu in (6436,6439)
   '''
try:
    #establish connection with profit (oracle) db
    con = cx_Oracle.connect(user='uid', password='pass', dsn='dsn_name')
    df0 = pd.read_sql_query(q0, con) 

except Exception as e:
    #return error message
    print("Error: " + str(e))
```

The key of was the cx_Oracle package which fetched the results in 20 seconds vs 8 minutes for pypyodbc (and 27 seconds for PLSQL as above).  I was also able to feed feed the rows directly into the dataframe in pandas via .read_sql_query

I'm still very interested as to why pypyodbc was so slow versus other options.  If anyone has any thoughts as to making it run faster, whether thats:

- changing encoding at sql level so python doesn't have to handle
- changing number of items returned by DB each call (size of array/chunk size)
- changing to server side
- skipping the .execute or .fetchall steps (these still work with cx_Oracle it appears)

Please let me know

Comment: You might be able to further improve cx_Oracle's fetch performance by bumping the value of `cursor.arraysize` somehow ie. what you mentioned in your second point.  See 'Tuning with arraysize' in section 3.5 of https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/tutorial/Python-and-Oracle-Database-12c-Scripting-for-the-Future.html

Comment: Thanks Christopher!

Answer (score 0):

Use `turbodbc` library, it was the only way to upload fast: https://turbodbc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/getting_started.html